# Vectors are positive oriented.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, analytic-geometry

I yesterday posted about orientation of vectors I have question regarding that.

This is how we defined orientation.

Used from one point in the space non-flat(not in same plane) $OA$ $OB$ $OC$ triplet of vectors are called right triplet if man  sitting at point $C$  is seeing shortest rotation from $OA$ to $OB$(around point $O$) in the plane that is passing with points $O,A,B$ in the counter-clockwise direction.[image]

This is picture for that.

Now using this definition can you describe me how $(c,a,b)$ vectors are right-handed.

[image]

This is how I understand it but in this way it isn't in clockwise way?So it is negative oriented.
Thank you.

Comment: [Same question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4189881/why-this-vectors-has-negative-orientation)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yes I mentioned in my post. In previous post I didn't understand fully.

Comment: In that case, I think it's best to delete your other question to forestall others from expending time and effort to answer it.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Ok I deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your final picture, you aren't sitting at point $B$. You are sitting on the opposite side of the plane $OAC$ from point $B$. Thus any rotation you see in that plane has the opposite direction from what a person at $B$ would see.

Comment: I finally understand it thank you!!.